# blur all the images except the selected area in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

My requirement is to blur the image while keeping it unblur in the selected area. I placed a div over the image by positioning it absolutely. Image is visible only in this area apart from this area all other image is blurred.

Here is my DOM structure

```
<div className="col-md-12 align-center mgb-30">
//within this area image is unblur while rest of image is blurred
<div className="venue-image-filter flex all-center color-white">
<h3 className="heading">Visible Area</h3>
</div>
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg" className="border-radius-10" alt="Venue" />
</div>
```

Styling of filter div

```
.venue-image-filter
{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
width:300px;
height:200px;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: `filter:blur(5px)`?

Comment: but it will blur all the images, how can I unblur image for the selected area?

Comment: I don't know!! You haven't shown nearly enough in your question to be able to "target" a particular image - and since there are no images within the `.venue-image-filter` div, then I can't possibly guess - I mean .. what is this **selected area image** - please clarify

Comment: how you specifying your selected area on mouse hover, on select ? are you adding some class to selected area? you question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little demo how you could do this:

```js
document.querySelector('.image').addEventListener('mousemove', ({ offsetX, offsetY, target }) => {
  const x = offsetX / target.clientWidth;
  const y = offsetY / target.clientHeight;
  target.style.setProperty('--x', `${x * 100}%`);
  target.style.setProperty('--y', `${y * 100}%`);
});
```

```css
.image {
  width: 640px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.image::before, .image::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: var(--image);
}

.image::before {
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.image::after {
  clip-path: circle(20% at var(--x, 50%) var(--y, 50%));
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" style="--image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/862/640/200)"><div>
```

Comment: This is only a general idea, you need to calculate the area of the `clip-path` yourself.